# Помогите исправить Javascript код

Tags: javascript

Есть код, который при уменьшении размера экрана до 800 пикс. выводит после заголовка дополнительный код:

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  var width = $('body').innerWidth()
  if (width < 800) {
    $(".zag").after("<p class='dop'>Дополнительный Текст</p>");
  }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Скрытие Блока в зависимости от разрешения монитора</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="zag">Заголовок</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Сейчас выводится несколько строк одинакового кода, типа лог файл. 
Нужно что бы код вывелся только один раз при изменении экрана.

Comment: Говорят, в соседней теме, в jQuery, есть функция .stop() Мне кажется, она прямо для Вашего случая

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  var width = $('body').innerWidth();
  if (width < 800) {
    if ($(".dop").length == 0) {
      $(".zag").after("<p class='dop'>Дополнительный Текст</p>");
    }
  } else {
    $(".dop").remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: О! Отлично! Спасибо! 
А можете подсказать как ещё добавить условие что бы при возврате прежнего размера блок снова пропадал?

Comment: @EXID Запросто.

Comment: Отлично! То, что нужно!